# OpenCL script giving unexpected results

Tags: java, image-processing, opencl, image-manipulation, jocl

I have this simple block of `OpenCL` code, and I am getting unexpected results. The parameters `image` is an array of floats and `value` is a number from -255 to +255. Using java I use a JSlider to change the `value`. The default value is 0 and the problem is when I move the slider more than 0 the image is black, if I move it less than 0 the image is white, which shouldn't happen. This should be checking each pixel individually and adjusting that pixel. It doesn't seem to be for some reason.

This block of code should change the threshold of an image. Which is any pixel that's Red Green and Blue is greater than the threshold should be white otherwise it should be black.

```
kernel void threshold(global float* image, const float value, const int max){
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    if (index >= max){
        return;
    }

    int color = image[index];
    int red = color >> 16 & 0x0FF;
    int green = color >> 8 & 0x0FF;
    int blue = color & 0x0FF;

    if(red > value && green > value && blue > value){
        red = 255;
        green = 255;
        blue = 255;
    }else{
        red = 0;
        green = 0;
        blue = 0;
    }

    int rgba = 255;
    rgba = (rgba << 8) + red;
    rgba = (rgba << 8) + green;
    rgba = (rgba << 8) + blue;

    image[index] = rgba;
}
```

If I replace the `if/else` statement in the middle with this:

```
red += value;
if(red > 255){red = 255;}
else if(red < 0){red = 0;}

green += value;
if(green > 255){green = 255;}
else if(green < 0){green = 0;}

blue += value;
if(blue > 255){blue = 255;}
else if(blue < 0){blue = 0;}
```

I get the result I am looking for, for that operation, which this is to adjust the brightness of an image.

I'm I using `OpenCL` wrong? From what I understand, is `kernel` will be called until the return is hit. I am using JOCL in java to do this, here is the code I am using to call it:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pocketshop.graphics;

import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.opencl.CLBuffer;
import com.jogamp.opencl.CLCommandQueue;
import com.jogamp.opencl.CLContext;
import com.jogamp.opencl.CLKernel;
import com.jogamp.opencl.CLPlatform;
import com.jogamp.opencl.CLProgram;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import pocketshop.Canvas;
import pocketshop.dialogs.BrightnessContrastDialog;

/**
 *
 * @author Ryan
 */
public class CL {

    protected static CLBuffer<FloatBuffer> buffer;
    protected static float[] pixels;

    public static CLBuffer<FloatBuffer> getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

    public static float[] getPixels() {
        return pixels;
    }

    public static void start(String script, float val) {

        CLPlatform platform = CLPlatform.getDefault(/*type(CPU)*/);
        CLContext context = CLContext.create(platform.getMaxFlopsDevice());
        try {
            CLProgram program = context.createProgram(getStreamFor("../scripts/" + script + ".cl"));
            program.build(CLProgram.CompilerOptions.FAST_RELAXED_MATH);
            assert program.isExecutable();

            BufferedImage image = Canvas.image;
            assert image.getColorModel().getNumComponents() == 3;

            pixels = image.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), (float[]) null);
            FloatBuffer fb = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(pixels);

            // allocate a OpenCL buffer using the direct fb as working copy
            buffer = context.createBuffer(fb, CLBuffer.Mem.READ_WRITE);

            // creade a command queue with benchmarking flag set
            CLCommandQueue queue = context.getDevices()[0].createCommandQueue(CLCommandQueue.Mode.PROFILING_MODE);

            int localWorkSize = queue.getDevice().getMaxWorkGroupSize(); // Local work size dimensions
            int globalWorkSize = roundUp(localWorkSize, fb.capacity());  // rounded up to the nearest multiple of the localWorkSize

            // create kernel and set function parameters
            CLKernel kernel = program.createCLKernel(script.toLowerCase());
            //adjustment(val, queue, kernel, buffer, localWorkSize, globalWorkSize);

            kernel.putArg(buffer).putArg((float) val).putArg(buffer.getNIOSize()).rewind();
            queue.putWriteBuffer(buffer, false);
            queue.put1DRangeKernel(kernel, 0, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize);
            queue.putReadBuffer(buffer, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        context.release();
    }

    private static InputStream getStreamFor(String filename) {
        return BrightnessContrastDialog.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
    }

    private static int roundUp(int groupSize, int globalSize) {
        int r = globalSize % groupSize;
        if (r == 0) {
            return globalSize;
        } else {
            return globalSize + groupSize - r;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out after many trial and error tests, that `int color = image[index];` is actually a Red Green or Blue color not an int of the 3.

so,

```
image[0] = Red;
image[1] = Green;
image[2] = Blue;
image[3] = Red;
image[4] = Green;
image[5] = Blue;
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your image is array of floats?
if yes, then you shouldn't do integer manipulations on it

if it's an rgba with one byte per component try to use uchar4 data type, maybe that's more suitable, you can perform vector operations on all 4 components in parallel.

also try to use opencl's clamp function for enforcing the range 0..255